# When to remove hops and other bittering/aroma agents?

Tags: hops, wort, boil

On brew day, when is the appropriate time to remove the hops and other bittering/aroma agents from the wort? Is it at flameout, or is it once the wort has been fully cooled and is ready for the primary fermenter?

In my case specifically, I am curious about an addition of orange peel at 1 minute left in the boil of a witbier. I didn't feel like it had quite enough time to fully do it's job when I removed all the bags at flameout.

Will leaving them in during the wort cooling result in any off flavors or aromas? Or is this actually what it needs to fully serve its late addition purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I leave everything in until after the wort is chilled.  If I use pellet hops, they go through the pump and into the fermenter.  In over 400 batches done like this, it hasn't caused any problems.

Comment: Wow. And no problems even on beers with a lot (5oz+) of pellet hops I'm assuming? That's pretty cool. I'm dumping in all my cold break now too, so this could be one less thing to worry about.

Comment: Nope, no problems.

Comment: Do you filter it out at all? Or does it settle into the trub ok?

Comment: It all settles out in the fermenter.

Answer (score 2):

I leave everything in while chilling. I have a funnel with a very fine mesh screen which will catch any debris while transferring from the pot to primary.